# Are any of Peter Parker's early costume designs allusions to the comic books?

Tags: reference, comic-adaptation, spider-man, spider-man-trilogy

In the first Spider-Man movie, when Peter is deciding to become a costumed wrestler, he sketches out a handful of possible costume designs that don't look much like a Spider-Man suit, but do look a lot like something one might find somewhere in a comic book.  Are any of them allusions to actual suits that were worn by Marvel Comics characters at some point?

Here's the clip from the film:

Comment: I know his wrestling costume is an allusion to his clone.

Answer (score 1):

There were only three costumes before the final one. One is from [Stingray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_%28comics%29), but it was put with <strike>utility belt</strike> sound like Batman-ish.

[image]

Stingray from comics:

[image]

It is bit debatable but [Dutch Wikipedia article](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_%28Marvel%29) assumes the same :

> Stingray’s kostuum is te zien tussen de vele schetsen voor een potentieel Spider-Man kostuum in de film Spider-Man.

The second costume I can relate with comics is Venom, the black costume he has drawn with the title "need more colour", it was just added with a bit red otherwise it was the same same as Venom's costume:

[image]

One more costume appear

[image]

Which look quite similar to his wrestling costume:

[image]

His wrestling costume is claimed to be inspired from [Ben Reily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Reilly) costume.

And then in the last his final costume appear :

[image]

Rest were just different angels of this costumes only.